# Making persistant entity Transient

Tags: hibernate

Consider a hypothetical scenario, is there a way in hibernate to make a persistant entity transient but at the same time does NOT delete the row in the database?
`session.delete()` would make it transient but at the same time issues a delete SQL for the database.

```
        //Persistant context started... 
        Session session2 = HibernateUtils.sessionFactory.openSession();
        session2.beginTransaction();

        Admin admin = (Admin) session2.load(Admin.class, 1L);
        session2.delete(admin);

        session2.getTransaction().commit();
        session2.close();
        //Persistant context ended...
        ...
        //admin now is transient but the row has been deleted, can we stop this?
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  However, you can use `session.evict()` (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object)) to make the object detached.  If you then set the primary key to 0 (or whatever), you get what is *effectively* a transient object with a full copy of the original's fields.  So you can do the following:

```
Foo foo = session.get(Foo.class, 1L);
session.evict(foo);
foo.setID(0L);
foo.setName("copy of original foo");
session.save(foo);
```

And you'll get a copy of foo with the new name.

(Be careful doing this when associations and cascading are involved.)